# Create systemd service unit in Linux

Tags: systemd, services

I want to create a systemd service module in Linux so that I don't have to enter commands at system startup:

```
cd /etc/mautrix-facebook/venv
source bin/activate
python3 -m mautrix_facebook
```

mautrix-facebook.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Matrix-Facebook bridge

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=~
ExecStart=/etc/mautrix-facebook/venv/bin/python3 -m mautrix_facebook
User=alex
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The module tries to start in /etc/mautrix-facebook/venv/bin and I am getting errors like:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.yaml'
```

How do I make the module run in /etc/mautrix-facebook/venv?

Comment: Try changeing `WorkingDirectory=~` to `WorkingDirectory=/etc/mautrix-facebook/venv`

Comment: @MaxSilvester Thanks! It works!